# Jruby rails - where should the java code go?

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

In my rails application I need to write some custom Java classes, so just wondering if there's any guidelines/best practice on how to structure the project repository? I mean like rails have a default directory structure in place, like app, models etc..., what should be the best place for my custom Java code?

Comment: I use `ext/`, much as a Rubygem with a C extension would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard recommended practice, but there are a few options:

- [ruby-maven](https://github.com/mkristian/ruby-maven) provides a DSL and a set of Rake plugins to build Java code the Maven way.
- [jruby-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/jruby-gradle/jruby-gradle-plugin) provides similar support for the Gradle build tool.
- For managing dependency libraries, there's also [jar-dependencies](https://github.com/mkristian/jar-dependencies).

If you're going to start writing Java/JVM code to go with your app, you'll probably need to integrate with the rest of the Java ecosystem at some point, and these tools are designed to support that.